# Migrating app from Bamboo to Cedar: can I just change DATABASE_URL in the new instance?

Tags: heroku, database-migration, bamboo, cedar

In the [migration Guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration) the recommended approaches for migrating databases don't include just changing the DATABASE_URL in the new instance. If you have a dedicated database in Bamboo, and want to use the same in Cedar, is there a problem in just pointing the DATABASE_URL in Cedar to the same DATABASE_URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the bamboo app, your DB will likely be decommissioned.  If you maintain your bamboo app, with just a single dyno and no workers it should be free, and the approach you suggest should work.